# php mysql add 1 year to date then compare if that new date will come in 30 days

Tags: mysql, date

I have been writing a small script that is supposed to check the expiration date 30 days prior to that date and send email reminder.

I have a table with column named `'completed'` meaning the date when the course has been finished, completed. Each course is valid for 1 year.

What I have been trying to do is first add one full year to '`completed`' then check if that new date falls exactly 30 days prior to `now().`

Example: the course was finished on 31 Dec 2012. It is valid until 31 Dec 2013, so if `TODAY` is 1 Dec 2013 email reminder should be sent.

I have this little script:

```
 SELECT distinct
     userID
     , completed+INTERVAL 1 YEAR AS expires
   FROM activity
  WHERE completed > NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

but obviously it doesn't do the job... 
Could anyone point me into right direction?

Thanks!
Cheers,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do for efficiency here is get the `+INTERVAL 1 YEAR` down into the WHERE.  You can do this using simple algebra.

```
completed + (1 YEAR) > NOW + (30 DAYS)
```

Is identical to

```
completed  > NOW + (30 DAYS) - (1 YEAR)
```

Giving

```
SELECT distinct
    userID,
    ADDDATE(completed,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS expires
FROM activity
-- Used CURRENT_DATE so that time of day is not a factor
WHERE completed > SUBDATE(ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 30 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Euhm, this:

```
SELECT distinct
     userID
     , completed+INTERVAL 1 YEAR AS expires
   FROM activity
  WHERE completed+INTERVAL 1 YEAR > NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: Thanks guys for really quick replies. I mucho appreciate it!